# IntelliJ IDEA is missing attributes of ui:repeat

Tags: jsf, intellij-idea

I am developing a JSF 2.2.12 application with IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2.1 Ultimate. The problem is that many of the attributes of `ui:repeat` (and possibly other components) are missing.

For example, I'd like to use the `step` attribute of `ui:repeat`, as defined [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/ui/repeat.html). When I attempt to use it, this is what happens:

[image: Attribute step is now allowed here]

If I ctrl + click on `repeat` to go to its source, and I am taken to the file

```
...\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2.1\plugins\JSF\lib\jsf-support.jar!\resources\schemas\ee7\tld\jsf-ui.tld
```

which has this definition of `repeat`:

```
<tag>
  <name>repeat</name>
  <tag-class></tag-class>
  <tei-class></tei-class>
  <body-content>JSP</body-content>
  <description>
    <![CDATA[
    The repeat tag should be used in almost all cases instead of the c:forEach to iterate over content with JSF.
    The repeat tag is often used in conjunction with the jsfc feature.
    ]]>
  </description>
  <attribute>
      <name>id</name>
      <required>false</required>
      <rtexprvalue>false</rtexprvalue>
      <description></description>
    </attribute>
  <attribute>
      <name>value</name>
      <required>true</required>
      <rtexprvalue>false</rtexprvalue>
      <description>The name of a collection of items that this tag iterates over. The collection may be a List, array, java.sql.ResultSet, or an individual java Object. If the collection is null, this tag does nothing.</description>
    </attribute>
  <attribute>
      <name>var</name>
      <required>true</required>
      <rtexprvalue>false</rtexprvalue>
      <description>The literal name of the variable to use while iterating.</description>
    </attribute>
</tag>
```

The only attributes defined are `id`, `value`, and `var`! Why are the other attributes not here?

Here is my `pom.xml` entry for JSF:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.12</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: The `...\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2.1\plugins\JSF\lib\jsf-support.jar` file is not maintained by JSF. It's maintained by IntelliJ. Report to them.

Comment: @BalusC Does that mean everyone using IntelliJ has this problem? Alright, I'll let them know